# mysql_pconnect vs odbc_connect (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, odbc

Sorry if this seems a basic question: but what are the differences between using mysql_pconnect vs odbc_connect for connecting to a MySQL database? Is odbc_connect designed such that it would be portable to other database types (e.g. Oracle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mysql_pconnect**  mysql_pconnect() is like mysql_connect() except, when connecting, the function would first try to find a (persistent) link that's already open with the same host, username and password. If one is found, an identifier for it will be returned instead of opening a new connection.

Second, the connection to the SQL server will not be closed when the execution of the script ends. Instead, the link will remain open for future use (mysql_close() will not close links established by mysql_pconnect()). You can read about it [here](https://www.php.net/mysql_pconnect).

**odbc_connect** just used to make db connections from php script. As its signature shows

```
resource odbc_connect (string $dsn, string $user, string $password [, int $cursor_type ])
```

it needs the database source name (dsn) for the connection. Alternatively, a DSN-less connection string can be used.
You can find more examples [here](https://www.php.net/odbc_connect)

**For your second question, yes odbc_connect is portable to other databases.**